# Access files on USB drive connected with OTG Adapter in Android

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-11, android-storage

I am trying to create an app for editing text files basically like a simple notepad.
My app is currently targeting android API level 29 i.e. `targetSdkVersion 29` and I am opting out of Scoped Storage for now using
`android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

I have added permissions,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Now, I want to read/write files from the USB drive connected using OTG adapter.
How do I find the find the path of the USB drive and access the files that will work even on devices running android R?
Is it possible to do it without using Storage Access Framework(SAF)?

Comment: is there a reason you dont wanna use the SAF?